# Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'Integer'

Tags: asp.net, sql, datatable

```
txtAddress.Text = DB.ProfileDataset.Tables("tblCustomers").Rows.Item("Address").toString
```

The above code generated Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'Integer' error under the **Item("Address")**
I don't know what i did wrong...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [DataRowCollection.Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.item.aspx) property requires an integer for the row index.

I think you are after the following syntax:

```
txtAddress.Text = DB.ProfileDataset.Tables("tblCustomers").Rows(0)("Address").ToString()
```

**EDIT**

Something to keep in mind:

```
original code
    = DB.ProfileDataset.Tables("tblCustomers").Rows.Item("Address").toString
compiler sees
    = DB.ProfileDataset.Tables.Item("tblCustomers").Rows.Item("Address").toString
fixed code
    = DB.ProfileDataset.Tables("tblCustomers").Rows(0)("Address").ToString()
compiler sees
    = DB.ProfileDataset.Tables.Item("tblCustomers").Rows.Item(0).Item("Address").ToString()
```